# How to pass the props data to another component correctly in Vue.js

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I'm trying to create a simple card component **CustomCard.vue** and re-use it on **HomeComponent.vue** page with specified data, so I've created a loop and put the needed data in `cards: []`

I don't know why it doesn't work. I can see the 3 elements on the page but they are displayed with the default values of the component, instead of taking the data from the `cards:[]`.

#### HomeComponent.vue:

```
...
<custom-card v-for="n in cards" :key="n">
   <img :src="n.cardImage" alt="">
   <p>{{n.cardDesc}}</p>
</custom-card>
...
<script>
  export default {
     data() {
        return {
           cardImage: "",
           cardDesc: "",
           cards: [
             {id: "1", cardImage: "../src/assets/img1.jpg", cardDesc: "some description 1"},
             {id: "2", cardImage: "../src/assets/img2.jpg", cardDesc: "some description 2"}, 
             {id: "3", cardImage: "../src/assets/img3.jpg", cardDesc: "some description 3"}
          ]
       }
     }
   }
</script>
```

#### CustomCard.vue:

```
<template>
    <div>
        <img :src="cardImage" alt="">
        <p>{{cardDesc}}</p>
    </div>  
</template>


<script>
    export default {
        data () {
            return {
                cardImage: "../src/assets/default.jpg",
                cardDesc: "default description text"
            }
        }
        // props: ['cardDesc', 'cardImage']
    }
</script>
```

---

I want these values below to be the default component values just as a placeholder (so I've put them in components data):

```
cardImage: "../src/assets/default.jpg",
cardDesc: "default description text"
```

If I pass the props out, I get an error: `[Vue warn]: The data property "cardImage" is already declared as a prop. Use prop default value instead.`

So I commented it out for now.

---

I've registered the **CustomCard.vue** globally in **index.js**:

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your component has no slots so there's no reason to include any content.

Seems to me you just need

```
<custom-card v-for="card in cards" :key="card.id"
             :card-desc="card.cardDesc"
             :card-image="card.cardImage" />
```

Note the `key` is set to the actual unique identifier for each iterable element.

---

You should of course un-comment the `props` declaration and remove the conflicting `data` keys from your component. As mentioned in the error message, you can also set default values

```js
export default {
  props: {
    cardDesc: {
      type: String,
      default: 'default description text'
    },
    cardImage: {
      type: String,
      default: '../src/assets/default.jpg'
    }
  },
  data () { // probably don't even need a data property
    return {}
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, that worked! I don't have the default component placeholder data that way, but I'm not sure I even need it, and it works now, so... Thanks, good explanation too!

Comment: @Un1 I've just updated my answer to include how to set default prop values

Comment: Ah, so I had to also add `type: String,` when specifying default values and use curly brackets. Thanks. I've been trying to learn how to do it for the last few hours and finally understand how it works!

Comment: @Un1 I think `type` is optional (it will default to `Object`). In fact, I think all prop validation properties are optional